# Wordpress Text editor does not work

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with my website. I made it with Wordpress ,

everything was Ok but I think that someone tried to hack it  today so all contents cannot be displayed .

To explain more when I write some text in text editor it's not showing on the front page of my website ! I don't understand what's the problem how can I solve it ?

http://www.ahlanfoundation.com/about-us/

```html
<p><span class="hide" style="color: #05ac63;"></span></p><h3 class="title bottom-2">من نحن ؟<span class="hide" style="color: #05ac63;"></span></h3><p></p>
<div class="fl-col fl-node-5820d492ec14e fl-col-small" data-node="5820d492ec14e">
<div class="fl-col-content fl-node-content">
<div class="fl-module fl-module-rich-text fl-node-5820d49fbdfa0 fl-animation fl-slide-right fl-animated" data-node="5820d49fbdfa0" data-animation-delay="0.0">
<div class="fl-module-content fl-node-content">
<div class="fl-rich-text">
<div id="panel-67-0-0-1" class="so-panel widget widget_sow-editor panel-last-child" data-index="1">
<div id="pg-67-1" class="panel-grid">مؤسسة أهلا للتسويق&nbsp;متخصصــة فــي التسويق الالكتروني&nbsp;نشــأت فكــرة تأسيســها لتكــون مؤسســة طموحــة تســعى لتقديــم حلــول مبتكــرة وابــداع لا محــدود فــي التسويق الالكتروني، وتفخــر&nbsp;المؤسسة بجذورهـا وهويتهـا و يدفعهـا الطمـوح لتوسـيع بـؤرة أعمالهــا . تأسســت أهلا للتسويق عــام&nbsp; 2016 لتصبــح إحــدى المؤسسات للتسويق&nbsp;الالكتروني الرائــدة فــي دول الخليج العربي وتضــع بمتنــاول جميــع العمــلاء خدمــات غيــر مســبوقة لكــي تصنــع الفــرق فــي حملاتهــم الترويجيــة والاعلانيــة لمختلــف أنشــطتهم وتوجهاتهــم . كمــا تضــم مؤسســتنا أفضــل العناصــر البشــرية مــن مختلــف الاختصاصــات لنقــدم خدمــات متميــزة تتماشــى مــع أدق متطلبــات عملائنــا المتغيــرة ســواء كانــت تصاميــم خاصــة أو الخطــط الإعلانيـة والاعلاميـة أو التسويق الالكتروني. نحـن نلتـزم بتقديـم أعلـى معاييـر الجـودة مـع إضافـة لمسـة مـن الابـداع الامحـدود.</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="fl-col fl-node-5820d492ec19c fl-col-small" data-node="5820d492ec19c"></div>
<p><span class="hide" style="color: #05ac63;"></span></p>
```

when I try to inspect some elements on the browser I found it hidden.

Comment: obiously this site has been hacked and users are redirected to some "chat" webite (porn stuff, it seems). If you have a full backup, erase everything and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you dont have a back up because you wouldent be posting this if you did!
Deactivate  all your plugins - install wp theme 2017 - delete your theme - re install your theme (from scratch) and activate your plugins one by one whilst checking the functionality of your theme. Your plugins are prob not the issue.

You can also inspect it in the browser if you can see the  first line - double  click

```
    <p><span class="hide"
```

and change it to

```
    <p><span class="show"
```

Then tap enter!